# Firefox is showing "Cannot find firefox binary in PATH." error in MAC OS

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Firefox is showing **"Cannot find firefox binary in PATH."** error in **MAC OS**. 
As per my understanding this issue occurs if the Mozilla is not installed in their default location. **I am new in MAC OS**

I have also tried with firefox profile and already I have set selenium provided DesiredCapabilities

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(new File("/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin")), profile);
```

I have also tried with different path of mozilla in MAC OS like:-

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox
/Applications/Firefox.app
```

Also please provide a snippet for the same.

Chrome is working fine for me in MAC OS. Only Mozilla is creating problem

Surely, I am missing something. I am attaching the snapshot regarding same.

Also, Is there any method present by which I can locate any application installed location using java code?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver there is a property you have to set to set the binary path:

```
webdriver.firefox.bin
```

so i assume you have to do following:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin","/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks man :) ......    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin","/Applications/Firefox20.0"); worked for me .. upvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed firefox, check whether the Firefox application is in the /Applications folder. If not move the application to /Application folder and run the test again.

If above worked, you don't have to add a system property "webdriver.firefox.bin"

Answer (score 0):

Possibly updated for the current situation with this I did this:

1. Installed [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/), available since 2018, to /usr/local/bin (arbitrary choice and made sure it could execute. This placement made it unnecessary to add it to my $PATH.
2. Installed Firefox to /Applications (I had the developer version)
3. Added this line to my setUp method: `driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxOptions().setHeadless(true));`

All this in macOS 10.11 "Big Sur" (aarch64) using current selenium.